# extract date to string from a json date string

Tags: java, android, json, jodatime

Android programming.
I have a json returning the date from a database as a string. How do I extract the date from the string using Joda or any other library to this format mm/dd/yy.
Here is the string 2012-05-22T00:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With standard JDK, you could use `SimpleDateFormat`

```
Date parsedDateInstance = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(dateString);

String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(dateInstance);
```

Comment: I get an error: Cannot convert from Date to String in the first line. and on second line I get: cannot convert from SimpleDateFormat to String.

Comment: First line should have Date parsedDateInstance, not String:

Comment: And the second line parsedDateInstance instead of dateInstance :)

Comment: @krzyk that is ok :) it is to represent any date instance would work here :)

Answer (score 2):

It's [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format so you can go with jodas:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(strInputDateTime);
```

And after that just format the DateTime object:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
String myDate = fmt2.print(dt)
```

This info is from http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Standard_Formatters

Comment: I get this error in the DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(). Invalid format: "2012-05-22T00:00:00" is too short

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that you don't have "Z" (timezone) attached, so this will not work for pure timezoneless date time.